# Solidity Token Sale?

Tags: solidity

How to build solid code Token Sale External?
For example SmartContract : 0x5bE7E9B948cd6d026585F72CC567879ffd0b629b

With fuction
- updateTokenPerEth

No need time.
Give me recommend code.

Answer (score 1):

Check OpenZeppelin-Solitity crowdsale contracts:
https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/tree/master/contracts/crowdsale

either pick one and use it, or inherit one of them and try to keep your alterations at minimum.

Answer (score 0):

The address you provided is a Ether Wallet Address. There are different types of Token Sale but the most proficinrt one is the `Crowdsale`. Here's; the code to create a crowdsale. Things you'll need
1. Token

So, here's the code to create tokens

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

interface tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData) external; }

contract TokenERC20 {
// Public variables of the token
string public name;
string public symbol;
uint8 public decimals = 18;
// 18 decimals is the strongly suggested default, avoid changing it
uint256 public totalSupply;

// This creates an array with all balances
mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

// This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

// This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients
event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint256 _value);

// This notifies clients about the amount burnt
event Burn(address indexed from, uint256 value);

/**
 * Constructor function
 *
 * Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract
 */
function TokenERC20(
    uint256 initialSupply,
    string tokenName,
    string tokenSymbol
) public {
    totalSupply = initialSupply * 10 ** uint256(decimals);  // Update total supply with the decimal amount
    balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;                // Give the creator all initial tokens
    name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
    symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
}

/**
 * Internal transfer, only can be called by this contract
 */
function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint _value) internal {
    // Prevent transfer to 0x0 address. Use burn() instead
    require(_to != 0x0);
    // Check if the sender has enough
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
    // Check for overflows
    require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);
    // Save this for an assertion in the future
    uint previousBalances = balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to];
    // Subtract from the sender
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;
    // Add the same to the recipient
    balanceOf[_to] += _value;
    emit Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    // Asserts are used to use static analysis to find bugs in your code. They should never fail
    assert(balanceOf[_from] + balanceOf[_to] == previousBalances);
}

/**
 * Transfer tokens
 *
 * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` from your account
 *
 * @param _to The address of the recipient
 * @param _value the amount to send
 */
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Transfer tokens from other address
 *
 * Send `_value` tokens to `_to` on behalf of `_from`
 *
 * @param _from The address of the sender
 * @param _to The address of the recipient
 * @param _value the amount to send
 */
function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);     // Check allowance
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
    _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Set allowance for other address
 *
 * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens on your behalf
 *
 * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
 * @param _value the max amount they can spend
 */
function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value) public
    returns (bool success) {
    allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
    emit Approval(msg.sender, _spender, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Set allowance for other address and notify
 *
 * Allows `_spender` to spend no more than `_value` tokens on your behalf, and then ping the contract about it
 *
 * @param _spender The address authorized to spend
 * @param _value the max amount they can spend
 * @param _extraData some extra information to send to the approved contract
 */
function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
    public
    returns (bool success) {
    tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
    if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
        spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
        return true;
    }
}

/**
 * Destroy tokens
 *
 * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly
 *
 * @param _value the amount of money to burn
 */
function burn(uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[msg.sender] >= _value);   // Check if the sender has enough
    balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;            // Subtract from the sender
    totalSupply -= _value;                      // Updates totalSupply
    emit Burn(msg.sender, _value);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Destroy tokens from other account
 *
 * Remove `_value` tokens from the system irreversibly on behalf of `_from`.
 *
 * @param _from the address of the sender
 * @param _value the amount of money to burn
 */
function burnFrom(address _from, uint256 _value) public returns (bool success) {
    require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);                // Check if the targeted balance is enough
    require(_value <= allowance[_from][msg.sender]);    // Check allowance
    balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                         // Subtract from the targeted balance
    allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;             // Subtract from the sender's allowance
    totalSupply -= _value;                              // Update totalSupply
    emit Burn(_from, _value);
    return true;
}
}
```

Here's the code to create a crowdsale

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

interface token {
function transfer(address receiver, uint amount) external;
}

contract Crowdsale {
address public beneficiary;
uint public fundingGoal;
uint public amountRaised;
uint public deadline;
uint public price;
token public tokenReward;
mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;
bool fundingGoalReached = false;
bool crowdsaleClosed = false;

event GoalReached(address recipient, uint totalAmountRaised);
event FundTransfer(address backer, uint amount, bool isContribution);

/**
 * Constructor function
 *
 * Setup the owner
 */
function Crowdsale(
    address ifSuccessfulSendTo,
    uint fundingGoalInEthers,
    uint durationInMinutes,
    uint etherCostOfEachToken,
    address addressOfTokenUsedAsReward
) public {
    beneficiary = ifSuccessfulSendTo;
    fundingGoal = fundingGoalInEthers * 1 ether;
    deadline = now + durationInMinutes * 1 minutes;
    price = etherCostOfEachToken * 1 ether;
    tokenReward = token(addressOfTokenUsedAsReward);
}

/**
 * Fallback function
 *
 * The function without name is the default function that is called whenever anyone sends funds to a contract
 */
function () payable public {
    require(!crowdsaleClosed);
    uint amount = msg.value;
    balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
    amountRaised += amount;
    tokenReward.transfer(msg.sender, amount / price);
   emit FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, true);
}

modifier afterDeadline() { if (now >= deadline) _; }

/**
 * Check if goal was reached
 *
 * Checks if the goal or time limit has been reached and ends the campaign
 */
function checkGoalReached() public afterDeadline {
    if (amountRaised >= fundingGoal){
        fundingGoalReached = true;
        emit GoalReached(beneficiary, amountRaised);
    }
    crowdsaleClosed = true;
}


/**
 * Withdraw the funds
 *
 * Checks to see if goal or time limit has been reached, and if so, and the funding goal was reached,
 * sends the entire amount to the beneficiary. If goal was not reached, each contributor can withdraw
 * the amount they contributed.
 */
function safeWithdrawal() public afterDeadline {
    if (!fundingGoalReached) {
        uint amount = balanceOf[msg.sender];
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = 0;
        if (amount > 0) {
            if (msg.sender.send(amount)) {
               emit FundTransfer(msg.sender, amount, false);
            } else {
                balanceOf[msg.sender] = amount;
            }
        }
    }

    if (fundingGoalReached && beneficiary == msg.sender) {
        if (beneficiary.send(amountRaised)) {
           emit FundTransfer(beneficiary, amountRaised, false);
        } else {
            //If we fail to send the funds to beneficiary, unlock funders balance
            fundingGoalReached = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

I'm still checking the code. There might be some errors, please do verify same!